# How to use ast.parse() inside interactive shell to parse a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this file:

```
>cat ~/tmp/junk.py
def foo(a, b, c = 100):
    return a + b + c

z = foo(10, 20)
print(z)
```

Then inside Python3.7 interactive shell:

```
>>> import ast
>>> root=ast.parse("", "~/tmp/junk.py")
>>> ast.dump(root)
'Module(body=[])'
>>> for node in ast.walk(root):
...   ast.dump(node)
... 
'Module(body=[])'
```

My goal is to check out the AST nodes of the function arguments, a, b and c. Could you help out what I did wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to pass `ast.parse` the actual source code you want to parse, not an empty string:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    tree = ast.parse(f.read(), filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

the first argument should contain code text. The second argument is only here for clear error messages.

You should read the file and pass the buffer:

```
filename = "~/tmp/junk.py"
with open(filename) as f:
   contents = f.read()
root=ast.parse(contents, filename)
```